# Dynamic table in html

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, spring

I would like to display data in table in jsp page from mysql in spring mvc and the table structure is not pre-defined (i.e)its column number changes.can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
String build="";build+="<table align='center' id='tab' width='75%' border='1'>";
    while(rs.next())
    {
        System.out.println("here innnn");
        build+="<tr>";
        for(int j=2;j<tcolcount+2;j++){
            build+="<td>"+rs.getString(j)+"</td>";
            last.add(rs.getString(j));
        }
        build+="</tr>";
    }
    build+="</table>";
```

Answer (score -1):

I would look at some example projects of Spring MVC. One of the best is the PetClinic example which you can find on GitHub [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/).

Once you have an understanding of this project I would try and modify this project to display your data.

Comment: i have gone through that but i didnt find any useful resource for my question.

Comment: Sorry, are you actually taking about dynamically created database tables and not html tables? Are you using hibernate/JPA or plain JDBC? Have a look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507758/how-to-map-dynamically-created-table-in-hibernate). For JDBC you can dynamically create your queries and Map then to some object type that you define and you can then use in your view.

Comment: yes bell am usin g the plain JDBC to connect to the database. Somehow i found a crude way of doin that.

Comment: tanQ bell for ur help