# How can I generate a 'create table' query based on user input data using JDBC/Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

Assume if we are giving the query data in a csv file as such below:

```
Emp_Id, Emp_Name, Address
```

Now, the query (Mysql) like below should be generated and processed.

```
Create TABLE Emp_tbl(
   Emp_id INT NOT NULL,
   Emp_Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   Address VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( Emp_id )
);
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Hibernate is used to map existing tables to entities. Not to create tables dynamically. Just use JDBC.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Can you please let me know how its possible using JDBC?

Comment: You execute the create table query, like any other query modifying the database, using a statement and executeUpdate(). Read the documentation. Try something.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by jdbc:

```
String sql_stmt = "Create TABLE Emp_tbl(
   Emp_id INT NOT NULL,
   Emp_Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   Address VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( Emp_id )
);";

public void createTable(String sql_stmt) throws SQLException {

    // your connection code
    statement = connection.createStatement();

    statement.executeUpdate(sql_stmt);
}
```

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507758/how-to-map-dynamically-created-table-in-hibernate) is about map dynamically created table in hibernate :

> It can be done dynamically, but it's somewhat messy:
>
> You'll need to dynamically alter Hibernate's Configuration object
>   before SessionFactory is built. If you're using Spring, this can be
>   done by overriding postProcessAnnotationConfiguration() method of
>   AnnotationSessionFactoryBean; otherwise you'll just need to do it
>   using your Configuration object prior to invoking
>   buildSessionFactory() on it.
>
> If you need to do this without application restart, you're looking at
>   either rebuilding your SessionFactory (which means your users will
>   have to wait until that's done) or using a separate SessionFactory
>   instance specifically dedicated to your custom classes (which is next
>   to impossible if your custom classes need to reference your built-in
>   classes).
>
> You can get access to class / table mappings via
>   configuration.getMappings(). You will then need to create a new table
>   mapping via Table API and add it to configuration via addTable(). Same
>   thing will have to be done with PersistentClass which represents a
>   class mapping. If you're using the same class to represent multiple
>   entities (e.g. map multiple tables) make sure to use unique entity
>   names for each. You'll have to do this (alter the configuration) on
>   every app restart.